# How to convert "true" and "false" to their boolean values?

Tags: python, csv

I need a list of bool named `REPORTED [" true "," false "," true "," false "," false "]` convert it to a type `bool: [true, false, true]` and then put it in a condition where I execute the following code that tries to get the average percentage of the total depending on 2 list in this case `s.Body [Physical appearance]` and `s.Reported [true: reported]` that is: calculate how many people with physical aspects `[fat, muscular, skinny]` were not `Reported [false]` and get the percentage of each aspect

My problem is that I don't need "true" or "false" (in str) if not in bool and I don't know how to put the condition to identify the bool that I think I converted

```
def porcentaje (Doc):
    Datos2 = [s.Cuerpo for s in Doc if s.DENUNCIADO ] #
    ConvertidorBool = list(map(lambda ele: ele == "false", Datos2))
    Datos=[s.Cuerpo for s in Doc if ConvertidorBool == "false"] # condicion
    CC = {Ca: Datos.count(Ca)*100/1000 for Ca in Datos if Ca !=""}
    Contador = Counter(CC)
    Agrupador = Contador.items()
    Porcentaje = dict(Agrupador)
    Resultado= print("{}".format(Porcentaje))
    return Resultado
```

Comment: `booled_result = [True  if _ == "true" else False for _ in origional_data]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the data are all `[" true "," false "," true "," false "," false "]` you can do:

```
li=[" true "," false "," true "," false "," false "]
>>> [True if "true" in s else False for s in li]
[True, False, True, False, False]
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> [True if s.strip()=="true" else False for s in li]
[True, False, True, False, False]

# [s.strip()=="true" for s in li] works too...
```

If there are unrelated strings in the source list, you can do:

```
>>> [True if "true" in s else False for s in [s for s in li if "true" in s or "false" in s]]
[True, False, True, False, False]
```

Or:

```
[True if s=="true" else False for s in [s for s in map(lambda x: x.strip(),li) if s=="true" or s=="false"]]
```

Or:

```
di={'true':True, 'false':False}
[di.get(s.strip(), None) for s in li]
```

Comment: thanks , thanks , thanks!!!

Comment: You can even make shorter to `[s.strip()=="true" for s in li]` since that will return `False` if s is not `"true"` for a list you know is just `true` and `false` strings.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(" true ".strip().title())
True
>>> ast.literal_eval(" false ".strip().title())
False
```

It looks like you just need to strip any surrounding whitespace in your values and capitalize them properly to create strings that contain exactly a `bool` literal.

However, `literal_eval` doesn't care about types, so if your list could contain non-Boolean literals like `"5"` or `"'foo'"`, then `literal_eval` will happily create `5` and `'foo'` for you. In that case, explicit comparisons are probably a better idea (and more efficient, too).

Comment: thanks for help me , Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've almost fixed it yourself. But I suggest you try to replace lines 3 and 4 with following:

```
    ConvertidorBool = list(map(lambda ele: ele == " true ", Datos2))
    Datos=[s.Cuerpo for s in Doc if ConvertidorBool == False] # condicion
```

Comment: thanks for helpme :3

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @dawg for his code I was able to make my str (bool) become the true bool I leave the code as I wrote it delete everything 1 by 1 I started adding:

```
def percentage (Doc):
    DataBool = [s.DENOUNCIADO for s in Doc]
    Converter_A_Bool = [True if "true" in s else False for s in DataBool]
    Data = [s.Body for s in Doc if Converter_A_Bool [0] == False]
    CC = {Ca: Datos.count (Ca) * 100/1000 for Ca in Data if Ca! = ""}
    Counter = Counter (CC)
    Grouper = Counter.items ()
    Dictionary = dict (Grouper)
    Result = print ("{}". Format (Dictionary))
    return Result
```